# PHP render multidimensional array in MVC

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a kind of MVC application with my own MVC implementation. Everything was fine, until I came up to render a multidimensional array I got from DB. my controllers have two function, to render a template and then render a layout with templates. I'm new to php and coding at all. Is it possible to render a multi array with my implementation?

code from controllerCatalog, it connects the model and get an array of main categories with nested array of subCategories if they exists:

```
class controllerCatalog extends Controller 
{
    protected $templateDir = 'home';

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->getModel('categories');
        $categories = $this->models['categories']->getAllCatsWithSubs();
        $menu = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $menu[] = $this->renderTemplate('menuCategories', $category);
        }
        $params['catMenu'] = $menu;
        echo $this->renderLayout($params);
    }
}
```

this is var_dump of $categories

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [catId] => 1
            [parentId] => 0
            [name] => smartphones
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [catId] => 4
                            [parentId] => 1
                            [name] => android_smartphones
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [catId] => 5
                            [parentId] => 1
                            [name] => apple_smartphones
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [catId] => 2
            [parentId] => 0
            [name] => tablets
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [catId] => 3
            [parentId] => 0
            [name] => laptops
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [catId] => 6
                            [parentId] => 3
                            [name] => windows
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [catId] => 7
                            [parentId] => 3
                            [name] => linux
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

here is renderTemplate function, which includes the necessary template and should fill it with data, and then renderLayout function takes templates as params for a main layout

```
protected function renderLayout($params = []) {
          foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
              $$param = $value;
        }
        ob_start();
        include_once APP_PATH . 'views' .  DS . 'layouts' . DS . $this->layout . '.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
}
protected function renderTemplate($template,$params, $templateDir = null) {
    $this->templateDir = $templateDir ?? $this->templateDir;
    foreach($params as $param=>$value) {
        $$param = $value;
    }
    ob_start();
    include_once APP_PATH . 'views' . DS . $this->templateDir . DS . $template . '.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and lastly the template where categories should be

```
<a href="/catalog/category?id=<?php echo $catId;?>"><?php echo $name;?></a>
<div class="sub_categorie">
<?php if (isset($childs)) {
    foreach ($childs as $child) {?>
        <a href="/catalog/category?id=<?php echo $child['catId']?>"><?php echo $child['name']?></a>
    <?php }?>
<?php }?>
</div>
```

the thing is that everything works, but it renders only first element of $categories array.
would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should `<?php` before your `foreach`

Comment: Is that multiple code blocks or does your file actually look like the above posted code? If they are different blocks, please add some title/explanation above each block so we know what we're looking at.

Comment: yeah that's different code blocks

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear what code goes where

Comment: You should also include a `var_dump()` of the array in question (at least an example so we know the structure) and an example of what you want and what you're currently getting. The question is pretty unclear at this point.

Comment: added everything that connects with my problem, please ask if any additions needed